# Calculus Apostol, 1.26 exercise 21 b

Tags: calculus, integration, absolute-value

I don't know how to solve this with the absolute value.

Find the value of c:
\[ \int_{0}^{c} |x(1-x)|dx=0 \]

Please, if possible, make a solution step-by-step. Thank you and sorry for the poor english.

Comment: If the absolute value is what's throwing you off, break in into to cases where $0 \le x \le 1$ and $|x(1-x)| = x(1-x)$ and where $x \ge 1$ where $|x(1-x)| = x(x-1)$.

Comment: One easy value is $c=0$ since $\int_{0}^{0} f(x)dx=0$ for any integrable function $f$ and your function being the absolute value of a continuous function si surely integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

If $c\le 1$, then $\frac{c^2}{2}-\frac{c^3}{3}=0$.

If $c>1$, then $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{c^3}{3}-\frac{c^2}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{c^2}{2}-\frac{c^3}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Now try it out.

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much, I'm a begginer in calculus.